# Bootstrap css specific layout row and column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, row, html

I want to this in bootstrap:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? Try reading the documentation http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

Comment: This : jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/5101 It's almost correct, it missed a well in the left bottom corner in the empty space..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work for you...

DEMO: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/YPA8Q/)

```
 <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='span8'>
            <div class='well tall'></div>
            <div class='well short'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='span4'>
            <div class='well short'></div>
            <div class='well tall'></div>          
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
//CSS
.short{
    min-height: 50px;
}

.tall{
    min-height:300px;
}
```